# Facebook App and Games Groups API - (#3) App must be on whitelist

Tags: facebook, facebook-game-groups

I am trying to create a group the App and Games group API, using the Graph API explorer. I am getting the following error. Do you have to be an approved app center app to be able to use this feature?

(#3) App must be on whitelist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there's a note to this effect on [the App and Game Groups documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/app-game-groups/):

> Your app must be in the App Center to be able to use Game Groups.

And on the [blog post which announced the feature](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/11/14/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/):

> To ensure a high quality experience for users, we're making this
>   feature available as a **beta to all apps and games listed in App
>   Center**, and will continue to iterate over time. You can get started
>   now by reading our concepts and reference documentation.